# Add fragment to listview

Tags: android

I want to make a card-flip mini-game. I followed [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html).

I have a `listview` whose child contains three `fragment`s that represent each card-flip. So, in a custom `adapter`, I have to add three `fragment`s to each row (cell).

 I define the layout in XML with fixed ids, but when I add a `fragment` to a row, every row appears in the first row.

 My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_one"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/common_thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/common_thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/imgv_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_imgv_add_image_bg" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_two"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/common_thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/common_thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/imgv_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_imgv_add_image_bg" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_three"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/common_thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/common_thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/imgv_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_imgv_add_image_bg" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My MemoryFragmentCell (listview's cell)

```
public class MemoryFragmentCell extends HWCell {
    public FrameLayout[] layout;

    public MemoryFragmentCell(Context context, View rootView) {
        super(context, rootView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initUiComponents(View rootView) {
        layout = new FrameLayout[3];
        layout[0] = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_one);
        layout[1] = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_two);
        layout[2] = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_three);
    }
}
```

My custom `Adapter`

```
public class MemoryAdapter extends
        HWArrayAdapter<ArrayList<MemoryBackItemFragment>> {
    private Context context;
    private int dimenMinimumHeight;

    public void setDimenMinimumHeight(int dimenMinimumHeight) {
        int padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(
                R.dimen.imgv_padding);
        this.dimenMinimumHeight = dimenMinimumHeight - 2 * padding;
    }

    public MemoryAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0, null);
    }

    private Activity activity;

    public MemoryAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<MemoryBackItemFragment>> objects,
            int dimenMinimumHeight, Activity activity) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_fragment_lv_memory, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.dimenMinimumHeight = dimenMinimumHeight;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MemoryFragmentCell cell = null;
        ArrayList<MemoryBackItemFragment> listItems = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fragment_lv_memory,
                    null);
            cell = new MemoryFragmentCell(context, convertView);
        } else {
            cell = (MemoryFragmentCell) convertView.getTag();
        }
        convertView.setMinimumHeight(dimenMinimumHeight);

        // setLayoutParams and data
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) cell.layout[0].getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = 1f;
        // params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        if (getCount() < 4) {
            params.height = (int) (dimenMinimumHeight / 1.5);
            params.width = (int) (dimenMinimumHeight / 1.5);
        } else if (getCount() < 5) {
            params.height = (int) (dimenMinimumHeight / 1.2);
            params.width = (int) (dimenMinimumHeight / 1.2);
        } else {
            params.height = dimenMinimumHeight;
            params.width = dimenMinimumHeight;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {
            cell.layout[i].setLayoutParams(params);
//          int id = 2 * position + i + 1;
//          cell.layout[i].setId(id);
            MemoryBackItemFragment backItemFragment = listItems.get(i);
            CommonHelpers.changeFragmentWithFlag(
                    activity,
                    cell.layout[i].getId() // TODO
                    , backItemFragment, true, CHANGE_FRAGMENT_TYPE.FLIP,
                    backItemFragment.getFlag());
        }

        convertView.setTag(cell);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Screenshot: [image]

 I tried to use `View.setId()` method but it's doesn't work. What can i do?

Comment: Show your Code and for fliping instead of Fragment you can use ViewFliper as child of fragment.

Comment: @SilentKiller: let see my editing!